# IntelliJ IDEA showing all maven plugins twice in maven toolbar tree

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, plugins

I have a maven project. Whenever I try to open it in IDEA, all plugins are shown twice in the tree. I have tried restart, invalidate caches / restart, checkout project again, clear .m2 folder, checking maven settings file.

[image]

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2 ( Community Edition )
Build #IC-193.6015.39, built on January 21, 2020

Runtime version: 11.0.5+10-b520.30 amd64

I couldn't find any solution. Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you please show your pom file..

Comment: Which part of my pom? It is too long.

Comment: best would be to put that on a github etc. excerpts don't really help... BTW: Does the project build on plain command line?

Comment: I cann't put the project github because no internet connection exist on the computer. Because of that putting pom file is really hard. Project build on command line succesfully.

Comment: And how are you writing comments / questions here? Without a pom file it's not really possible to help...

Comment: I have two computer. One of them connected to the internet and the other is not. Development machine which is restricted to copy any data to other computer. I am looking for someone who may have encountered this problem before with this much information.

Comment: If your project is confidential you probable need to hire a Maven/IntelliJ consultant instead of asking people on the internet.

Comment: If Intellij is confused (which lack of internet connection may be a part in) then you might want to do a fresh checkout/clone from version control (where .idea/ should not be in) and open it again.

Comment: Bug report posted on JetBrains site, linking to this Question: [*IDEA-232114*](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-232114). By the way, this bug bit me too, in IntelliJ 2019.3.2.

Comment: Yes, I created it. They solved the problem with version 2020.1 but not released for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three immediate things that you could try, that could help:

1. Reimport the maven project. IntelliJ tries to parse your pom and build an object model based on the information found in the pom. There is a button that looks like two arrows that form a circle in the maven tab.
2. Close the project and open up the pom.xml again (its important, not the .idea or something, but a pom.xml). It will offer you to delete the current definitions and create new. Do it and it will rebuild everything.
3. `File --> Invalidate Caches --> Restart`. It will invalidate intelliJ caches (obviously) and restart the IDE.

Comment: I deleted all the files related to my project. I pulled again. I imported it. Problem solved. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Invalidate Caches work for me, test with IDEA 2019.3.1

Comment: This problem occurs when I change the dependency version in the pom file, as I don't understand. I delete .idea file and import the maven project again. This is how I solved the problem.

Comment: Same problem for me with IDEA 2019.3.3.  This 3 step procedure fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

1. Close your project from File menu. `File--> close project`
2. Go to your project directory and delete `.idea` and any file with extension `.iml`
3. Right-click on your pom and open it with IntelliJ or reimport your project from IntelliJ.

Comment: The problem is resolved when I follow these steps. But when I close the project and open it again, the same problem still occurs. It is impossible for me to repeat these operations constantly. It is more like a temporary solution. I installed the Idea 2019.2.2 version. This version is working properly.