# All the plugins appear twice on the "Maven" panel in IntelliJ for Vaadin 14 project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, vaadin, maven-plugin, vaadin-flow

I have been surprised to find all the items in *Plugins* section of the *Maven* panel in IntelliJ 2019.3.2 to be repeated, two items for each plugin appears redundantly.

Yesterday, I replaced my entire project with a new fresh project from the "Plain Java Servlet" flavor of the [Vaadin starter site](https://vaadin.com/start/latest). I copied over all the relevant files. Things went well for some hours. Now, again, the double listing has appeared. A mystery me to me, I did not notice when it happened. Perhaps related to changing my POM to using a slightly later updated version of Vaadin, and re-imported the POM. I have done so many times on many projects, but this problem seems to have appeared only this week.

See this screenshot. Notice `clean` followed by `clean`, `compiler` followed by `compiler`, `deploy` followed by `deploy`, and so on.

[image: Screenshot of Plugins section of Maven panel in IntelliJ 2019.3 with all plugin items appearing in the list twice, redundantly.]

➥ What is causing this double listing of "Plugins" items?

➥ How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ IDEA showing all maven plugins twice in maven toolbar tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59962386/intellij-idea-showing-all-maven-plugins-twice-in-maven-toolbar-tree)

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Unfortunately, none of the items in either [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59967489/642706) or [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60053343/642706) helped at all.

Comment: Please check the issue with 2020 EAP: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ .  Seems it should be fixed there: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-232114